# Rake assets:precompile gets killed when there is a console session open in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

On my production server, which is hosted on digital ocean, if that helps, Ubuntu 12.04, I have RoR 4 and rake 10.1.1.

When I deploy, I run `rake assets:precompile`, and I've noticed a strange issue where if I have a `rails console` session open when I do this, I get the following output

```
~# rake assets:precompile
~# Killed
```

It's mainly annoying, but the reason I want it resolved is when hiring new developers, there will be deploy/console conflict nightmare.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your precompile process is probably being killed because you are running out of RAM. You can confirm this by running `top` in another ssh session. To fix this, create a swap file that will be used when RAM is full.

**Create SWAP Space on Ubuntu**
You will probably end up needing some swap space if you plan on using Rails on Digital Ocean 512MB RAM droplet.  Specifically, you will run out of RAM when compiling the assets resulting in the process being quietly killed and preventing successful deployments.

To see if you have a swap files:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

No swap file shown? Check how much disk space space you have:

```
 df
```

To create a swap file:

Step 1: Allocate a file for swap

```
sudo fallocate -l 2048m /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Step 2: Change permission

```
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Step 3: Format the file for swapping device

```
sudo mkswap /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Step 4: Enable the swap

```
sudo swapon /mnt/swap_file.swap
```

Step 5: Make sure the swap is mounted when you Reboot. First, open fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Finally, add entry in fstab (only if it wasn't automatically added)

```
# /etc/fstab
/mnt/swap_file.swap none swap sw 0 0
```

Save and exit. You're done adding swap.  Now your `rake assets:precompile` should complete without being killed.

Comment: I think I'm just going to buy more computer, thanks for the answer though this makes sense!

Comment: If fallocate `failed: Operation not supported` then use this instead `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/swap_file.swap bs=1024 count=2097152`

Comment: I just encountered this issue again, but this with with capistrano.  Cap deploy fails on precompiling assets and errors with "Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/...".  The steps above still worked and solved the issue.

Comment: Ran into the same problem deploying on the AWS elastic beanstalk t1.micro free tier. This solved the issue.

Comment: This is one of the best Stack Overflow answers I have ever read.  Thank you!  Confirmed working on elastic beanstalk Micro 5/12/17!

Answer (score 1):

`Rake assets:precompile` is a memory eating process.

So make sure you have enough RAM before using that command

Answer (score 0):

I have an opsworks stack on aws and I'd to change my instance type. 
I was using t1.micro and i just changed it to t1.small

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a lot of RAM. To check how much available RAM memory you have free, use the command

`free -m`

This will show the available RAM in MB

A temporary solution would be to create a swap space.

I was going to add this as a comment to Jason R post above before you go into his steps, just to make sure it is a RAM resource issue.

you could also run

`echo {1,2,3} > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

to clean up the cache memory, but it probably will not free up enough.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. For me, since i couldn't use 'fallocate' command, i had to do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/4GB.swap bs=4096 count=1048576
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/4GBB.swap
sudo mkswap /mnt/4GB.swap
sudo swapon /mnt/4GB.swap
```