# Rails Asset Precompile take a long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline, capistrano3

My asset precompile tales almost 15 minutes in production due to which sometimes it abort.

My other projects doesn't take such a long time. It looks that it takes a long time even to start the task.

following is the log.

```
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled jquery1.10.2.js  (2ms)  (pid 4828)
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled jquery-ui.min.js  (1ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled admin.js  (270ms)  (pid 4828)
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled jquery.nicescroll.js  (1ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled application.js  (1031ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js  (1ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled jquery.autocomplete.css  (108ms)  (pid 4828)
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled admin.css  (728ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Compiled application.css  (354ms)  (pid 4828)

...... (some assets which took 0ms)

DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Processed digest assets in 418179ms
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     Copied binary asset to 12maple.jpg
DEBUG[b6fdcae6]     ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is but I faced a similar problem trying to deploy an app to Digital Ocean, the specs of the dropplet was minimum so the RAM and the shared memory was very small causing the abort of the deploy in the precompile task. I solved the problem increasing the size of the shared memory and the RAM.

These links helped me to solve the problem, hope help you too.

Increase RAM:

[Rake assets:precompile gets killed when there is a console session open in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272339/rake-assetsprecompile-gets-killed-when-there-is-a-console-session-open-in-produ)

Increase shared memory:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0182/fxxua/index.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/710264/failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-cannot-allocate-memory

http://rwitkop.com/VistA/ConfigureSysctl4Cache.html